# how to override func with autocompletion

Tags: swift, xcode

## EDIT

Just restart xcode, and everything works. Seems xcode got stuck in something.

## ORIGIN

I'm new to swift, and I want to write a custom UICollectionViewCell.
But I found autocompletion just don't work. In **objc** I can autocomplete `initWithFrame:` by typing **"- initWithF" + TAB**, But no matter what I tried in swift it always shows no completion or other stuff.

So what is the key word to override a function in swift? Or does swift broke in xcode 8.3?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to add these two functions:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
```